# Gmail mail server

Tags: python, gmail

I used use Google’s slick interface to get my mail and It’s always going to be here:

https://mail.google.com/a/yourdomainhere.com

I want to write python script that send mail so i failed to configure server settings

```
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('mail server should be what?', what is the port)
smtp.login('username@yourdomainhere.com', 'pass')
```

Please could any one help me ??

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All on gmail's support site, see http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Comment: I tried 

    smtp = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    smtp.login('username@domain.com', 'pass')

i got the following error 
"
 raise SMTPException("SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
 SMTPException: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.

"

Comment: If you had read the link you'd see that you must use TLS or SSL.  I believe SMTPlib supports TLS, so you should be ok, as long as you start the TLS session.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

But how can i start a TLS session ?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the help:
http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Its smtp.gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

The preferred method for SMTP message forwarding is using your ISP's SMTP server. The job of locating Google's [Message transfer agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent) is handled by such servers.

To use Google's servers directly, you need to look up the [MX records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) provided by google via DNS. From a `Python` program, a DNS library is needed. Here is an example, using [`dnspython`](http://www.dnspython.org/), a A DNS toolkit for Python.

```
>>> from dns import resolver
>>> mxrecs = resolver.query('gmail.com', 'MX')
>>> [mx for mx in mxrecs]
[<DNS IN MX rdata: 20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.>, 
<DNS IN MX rdata: 40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.>,
<DNS IN MX rdata: 30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.>,
<DNS IN MX rdata: 10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.>,
<DNS IN MX rdata: 5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.>]
>>> mx.exchange.to_text()
'gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.'
>>> mx.preference
5
>>>
```

The preferred mail-exchange server here is `gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com`, which can be used with [`smtplib`](http://docs.python.org/library/smtplib.html) to forward messages.